# HTTPS GET request to web service timeout (passes through load balancer)

Tags: web-services, load-balancing

I have a load balancer setup for my web service server

Now, when I try to invoke GET requests to said server and the data being returned to me is relatively small (xml format text), it works fine.

But, once I refine the parameters of my GET request to pull in more results, it produces a timeout (as evidenced by access logs in my load balancer).

This happens everytime I try to invoke the web service in HTTPS, but when I do it in HTTP, no matter how large the data set being returned is, it always works.

I don't know whats happening and I do not know much about HTTP and HTTPS to investigate on my own

I am using Barracuda Load Balancer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that it has to do with the Real Server settings within my Load Balancer. The HTTPS protocol was only enabled for the client to load balancer requests but not the load balancer to real server requests. I fixed this by modifying the load balancer to use the HTTPS (443) port of the real server.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Network Monitor. There could be a problem with HttpWebRequest Usually it get stuck at a stage where it's supposed to send back a client key exchange. It simply didn't. The server usually waits for it, but it never come.

Try enforcing the SSL3  TLS (even though TLS is supposed to automatically turn into SSL3 if necessary)

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```